# How to redirect MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED to a different Node?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a Region called 'R', and a Node called 'N'.  N is the only child on R.  Consider this behaviour:

1. the user presses the left-mouse button on some part of R
2. N (which is somewhere else on R) moves so that it is centered on the spot where the user pressed
3. the user releases the left-mouse button, then presses it again without moving the mouse
4. with the left-mouse button still pressed, the user drags the mouse, and N now follows the mouse cursor around as it is dragged.

I have no problems implementing the behaviour I've just described.  I put a MOUSE_PRESSED handler on R that implements step 2.   And I put a MOUSE_DRAGGED handler on N that implements step 4.  JavaFX automatically directs the MouseEvents to these handlers on R and N for the presses in step 1 and 3 respectively.

**The Problem:**

I need to do this WITHOUT step 3.   That is, the user should not have to press-release-press-drag, but rather should simply press-drag, and N should "jump" to the mouse location on the "press", and then start receiving MOUSE_DRAGGED events immediately.

Unfortunately, this doesn't happen.  The release-click that I'm trying to omit seems to be necessary, otherwise the drag events all happen on R instead of N.

I'm thinking the solution will involve redispatching the initial MOUSE_PRESSED, or something along those lines.  Does anyone know a way to do this (or a better way to solve my problem?)

Comment: I should also mention that in practice I actually need to do this for a large number of different nodes (i.e. I have many N's) so I cannot rely on the region R to move N (see James_D's solution below.)  For reasons of encapsulation, I need to have N be in control of moving itself.

Comment: What is the logic you are using to determine which N should snap to the position of the initial mouse click?

Comment: I'm writing a custom API for displaying arbitrary nodes that are created by users of the API.  The 'currently active' node (as defined by the user) is the one that snaps to the mouse position.  It is also the Node that needs to receive the drag events, since the actual behaviour that occurs during those drags can also be customized (the behaviour I described in my simple example is only one of many possible reactions that used-defined Nodes might do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node has api to mark it as the target of drag gestures:

> public void startFullDrag()
>
> Starts a full press-drag-release gesture with this node as gesture
>   source. This method can be called only from a DRAG_DETECTED mouse
>   event handler. More detail about dragging gestures can be found in the
>   overview of MouseEvent and MouseDragEvent.

Assuming circle being your currently active node in a pane (borrowing code/names from James's answer), the collaborators are handlers on

- mousePressed on pane that snaps the position of circle to the the current location
- dragDetected on pane that calls startsFullDrag on circle
- dragAny on circle that does the actual moving

In code:

```
pane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        circle.setCenterX(event.getX());
        circle.setCenterY(event.getY());
    }
});
pane.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        circle.startFullDrag();
    }
});
circle.addEventHandler(MouseDragEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
        circle.setCenterX(event.getX());
        circle.setCenterY(event.getY());
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution for my situation, though the solution offered by James_D will work in many cases too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I chose the simplest node to work with for this, but I think this would work in general:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClickAndDragTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Pane pane = new Pane();
        final Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100, 50, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        pane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                circle.setCenterX(event.getX());
                circle.setCenterY(event.getY());
            }
        });
        pane.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                circle.setCenterX(event.getX());
                circle.setCenterY(event.getY());
            }
        });

        final Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; it is a good solution to the problem that I've described.  Unfortunately, I've described a highly simplified version of my problem, and I left out the fact that I need N to be in charge of it's own positioning code.  I cannot easily rely on R to position N.